# Characterization of $\mathrm{Im} f=\ker f$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ a finite dimensional space over a field $\mathbb F$ and $f\in\mathcal{L}(E)$. The question is to prove the equivalence of:

1. $\mathrm{Im} f=\ker f$
2. $f^2=0$ and there's $h \in\mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $hf+fh=\mathrm{id}$

I proved that $2.\Rightarrow 1.$ and $1.\Rightarrow f^2=0$ but I didn't know how complete the proof. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E$ is finite-dimensional we might pick a basis $v_1,\ldots ,v_m$ of $\ker f$ and, as $\ker f\subseteq \operatorname{im} f$, pick $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ with $f(w_i)=v_i$. Then $v_1,\ldots ,v_m,w_1,\ldots,w_m$ are linearly independant: Assume $$a_1v_1+\ldots +a_mv_m+b_1w_1+\ldots+b_mw_m=0. $$
Then after applying $f$ we obtain $b_1v_1+\ldots+b_mv_m=0$, hence $b_1=\ldots=b_m=0$ and then from $a_1v_1+\ldots +a_mv_m=0$ also $a_1=\ldots =a_m=0$. From $\dim\ker f+\dim\operatorname{im}f=\dim E$, we knwo that $\dim E=2m$, so this linearly independant system is a basis of $E$ (this is the only point where $\dim E<\infty$ is needed!). 
Now define $h$ by letting $h(v_i)=w_i$ and $h(w_i)=0$. Then $hf(v_i)+fh(v_i)=0+v_i$ and $hf(w_i)+fh(w_i)=w_i+0$ and hence $hf+fh=\operatorname{id}_E$.